# How to apply mouseover/mouseout/rollover to images in one picture library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, picture-library

I have the images like so in one picture lib.
Is there a way i can apply mouseover to these images e.g 
Originla images is : gin.jpg
and rollover is ginHover.jpg
without needing to create another pic lib

```
<div id="foo2">
<img width="130" height="130" alt="Virgin" src="/sites/gin.jpg">
<img width="130" height="130" alt="Optus" src="/sites/Op.jpg">
<img width="130" height="130" alt="Telstra" src="/sites/stra.jpg">
<img width="130" height="130" alt="OptusHover" src="/sites/OpHover.jpg">
<img width="130" height="130" alt="TelstraHover" src="/sites/straHover.jpg">
<img width="130" height="130" alt="VirginHover" src="/sites/ginHover.jpg">
</div>
```

THanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [css sprite](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) and upload a single image in the document library corresponding to the rollover.